# $_POST is empty after submitting a form with js method "submit()"

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I want to submit an html form via the javascript method `submit()`, instead of clicking on a submit button. This works for the most part, as the form is submitted, but `print_r($_POST)` shows the `$_POST` superglobal doesn't have a submit variable defined.

Using:
`<input type="submit" name="submit">` and `print_r($_POST)` prints `Array ( [submit] => Submit )`

Using: `myFunction(){document.forms["myForm"].submit()}` and `print_r($_POST)` returns "Array ( )"

I currently use `isset($_POST["submit"])` to check for a form submit, but obvioulsy this doesn't work if submit is never defined.

My questions are why "submit()" behaves differently from an "input type='submit'" and how I can check for a form submit without $_POST["submit"] being defined?

Since it was asked, the html for my form is

`<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>`

Comment: Please post the html inside the form, And what do you want to submit? here you have a button just.

Comment: I want to submit multiple files. my html is "<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>" for the files. When I add "<input type="submit" name="submit">" and use that for submitting the form to the php script, $_POST["submit"] is set. Using the "submit()" function, $_POST["submit"] is not set. I am wondering why that is, since the form is still getting submitted to the php script, as I can use and work with the files being submitted, if I delete "isset($_POST["submit"])". html for form is "<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">"

Comment: If you want to submit file, don't forget to add `enctype= multipart/form-data` to your `form` tag.

Comment: I edited the post with the full html code for my form. I didn't forget the `enctype= multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Does your javascript code submit the form?

Comment: I currently have 2 versions of this project. Version 1 the form is submitted via a press on the submit button within the form. Version 2, the form is submitted by pressing a button with `onclick="myFunction()"` and `myFunction(){document.forms["myForm"].submit()`. AGAIN, the form submits without problem, I'm jsut wondering why submit isn't set in $_POST superglobal, as that messes with `isset($_POST["submit"])`